# Declare A Variable Using Formula Or Combination Of Variables

Tags: java, variables, jsoup, combinations

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm trying to parse 50 different sites but I want it to happen 1 by 1 so I'll run the code below in a loop. The actual problem is here that when I run the variable linker it should display the link instead of the value A1. I don't know if I'm making sense, this is extremely difficult to explain but is there a way to make magic happen which may look something like this

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect( string (Alpha + counter)  ).get();
```

Where I can declare the variable named based on a formula/combination?

**Code**

```
String A1 = "http://www.randomwebsite1/home.html";
String A2 = "https://sites.google.com/a/organization/contact-us";
String A3 = "http://www.alright.com/index.html";
String A4 = "http://www.youtube.com/";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            int counter = 1;
            String Alpha = "A";
            String linker = Alpha + counter;
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(linker).get();
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you are doing?  Just put it in a for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just dynamically create a [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) [array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) and use an [enhanced for-loop](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with) to iterate it.

```
String[] urls = { 
        "http://www.randomwebsite1/home.html",
        "https://sites.google.com/a/organization/contact-us", 
        "http://www.alright.com/index.html",
        "http://www.youtube.com/" 
};

Document doc = null;
for (String url : urls) {
    doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  int n = 2  //provide the value here.It can be anything. It is the number of websites you want to loop.
  String[] A = new String[n];
    A[0] = "abc.com";
    A[1] = "xyz.com";

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
         Document doc = Jsoup.connect(A[i]).get();
    }
```

Is this too not working?

Comment: Eclipse is popping this error, "n cannot be resolved to a variable", I'm a beginner, is that the full code?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things wrong here...

First: you haven't declared your variable as static, so they will be unable to be accessed from within a static method (in your case: main).

Second: doing this like

```
int counter = 1;
String Alpha = "A";
String linker = Alpha + counter;
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(linker).get();
```

Doesn't work in Java (it can be done using reflection, but you really don't need to know about that for 99% of programming tasks)... let me walk you through what's happening:

1. counter is declared as an int with value 1
2. Alpha is declared as a String with value "A" (Java conventions dictate that variable names start with a lower case letter, but that won't affect execution)
3. linker is declared as a String with value "A1"
4. Jsoup.connect method is called with argument "A1"

To get the effect you want, you could try putting your urls in a String array and iterate through the array to get each one in turn (as shown in Nalin Agrawal's answer).

So in conclusion, either declare your variables static, or declare them inside the method, and declare them as an array of Strings and iterate through them instead of trying to build a variable name to be used.